# Is the call_user_func_array() changed in PHP 5.3?

Tags: php, callback

Has the function `call_user_func_array()` changed in `PHP 5.3` ? Because I have module that has several calls of this function, but it doesn't work after upgrade to `PHP 5.3`. I traced the code and it seems it doesn't call this function.

Should I change it?

Edited:

some cuts of codes:

```
function complete($message, $endpoint, $return_to)
{
    $mode = $message->getArg(Auth_OpenID_OPENID_NS, 'mode',
                             '<no mode set>');

    $mode_methods = array(
                          'cancel' => '_complete_cancel',
                          'error' => '_complete_error',
                          'setup_needed' => '_complete_setup_needed',
                          'id_res' => '_complete_id_res',
                          );
    $method = Auth_OpenID::arrayGet($mode_methods, $mode,
                                    '_completeInvalid');
    $method = '_complete_id_res';
    return call_user_func_array(array(&$this, $method),
                                array($message, $endpoint, $return_to));
}

/**
 * @access private
 */
function _complete_id_res($message, &$endpoint, $return_to)
{  
    $user_setup_url = $message->getArg(Auth_OpenID_OPENID1_NS,
                                       'user_setup_url');

    if ($this->_checkSetupNeeded($message)) {
        return new Auth_OpenID_SetupNeededResponse(
            $endpoint, $user_setup_url);
    } else {
        return $this->_doIdRes($message, $endpoint, $return_to);
    }
}
```

if I put die('*'); command in the second function,it doesn't die that show it doesn't enter it.

Comment: Please include a small working example that shows the problem.

Comment: ok,the code is long, let me cut some of it.

Comment: i not think that `&$this` shouldn't be just `$this`

Comment: I test what you said,but no difference.

Comment: I haven't write these codes,they are openID codes I fetched from internet, it was working well in php 5.2,after upgrade it doesn't work.

Comment: oh... check newver version of the code, probably in same source, but if you like to investigate turn on warnings and notice in php.ini

Answer (score 1):

why not check that on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) ?

> Changelog
>
> ```
> Version  Description
> ```

```
5.3.0    The interpretation of object oriented keywords like parent and self has
         changed.   Previously, calling them using the double colon syntax would emit an 
         E_STRICT warning because they were interpreted as static.
```

Comment: What? You're 9 seconds faster than me! (yeah I thought a moment before posting :P)

Comment: I also though 20 seconds before decide to post so stupid info :)

Comment: I checked it before asking this question. But I didn't understand what it says,so asked here.

Comment: @hd so you should tell more details, as they say exatly this

Comment: why are you so mean to give my question downvote ? it is a real question.

Comment: because answer is documented by vendor

Comment: but as I said I didn't understand what vendor says. maybe I am not professional programmer or clever like you.

Answer (score 0):

[Yes, it has changed.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php#refsect1-function.call-user-func-array-changelog)

> 5.3.0: The interpretation of object oriented keywords like parent and self has changed. Previously, calling them using the double colon
>   syntax would emit an `E_STRICT` warning because they were interpreted as
>   static.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved now. It was because of defining function parameters with reference(&) but the calling was with a value. I remove the '&' from function definition and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

It is solved now. The problem was function parameters that were defined by reference (&) in the function but were passed with value. I removed `&` from them and the problem was resolved.